# Isn't there a syntax error? Should printf("one" ", two and " "%s.\n", "three" ); be valid code?

Tags: c, gcc, syntax, c-preprocessor, string-literals

Take a look at this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define _ONE "one"
#define _TWO_AND ", two and "
int main()
{
    const char THREE[6] = "three" ;
    printf(_ONE _TWO_AND "%s.\n", THREE );
    return 0;
}
```

The `printf` is effectively:

```
printf("one" ", two and " "%s.\n", "three" );
```

and the output is:

> one, two and three.

`gcc` gives neither error nor warning messages after compiling this code.
Is the `gcc` compiler supposed work in that way, or is it a bug?

Comment: What did your gcc command look like?

Comment: You're obviously assuming that the code is invalid C. Why do you assume that?

Comment: I am not sure why two more votes to close due to not having an SSCCE occurred. The code definitely demonstrates what the OP desires to know is standard behavior or not and it indeed compiles and runs. Even when the original typos existed it was obvious what the questions intended.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is standard behavior, adjacent string literals are concatenated together if we look at  the [C99 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `5.1.1.2` *Translation phases* paragraph *6* says:

> Adjacent string literal tokens are concatenated

`gcc` does have many non-standard extensions, but if you build using `-pedantic` then `gcc` should warn you if it is  doing something non-standard, you can read more in the documents section [Extensions to the C Language Family](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Extensions.html#C-Extensions).

The rationale is covered in the [Rationale for International Standard—Programming Languages—C](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf) and it says in section `6.4.5` *String literals*:

> A string can be continued across multiple lines by using the backslash–newline line continuation, but this requires that the continuation of the string start in the first position of the next line. To permit more flexible layout, and to solve some preprocessing problems (see §6.10.3), the C89 Committee introduced string literal concatenation. Two string literals in a row are pasted together, with no null character in the middle, to make one combined string literal. This addition to the C language allows a programmer to extend a string literal beyond the end of a physical line without having to use the backslash–newline mechanism and thereby destroying the indentation scheme of the program. An explicit concatenation operator was not introduced because the concatenation is a lexical construct rather than a run-time operation.

Comment: Note that string literal concatenation is stage 6 of the processing; the preprocessor is stage 4, long before strings are concatenated.

Answer (score 3):

**You had not got any error because there was/is Nothing wrong.**

Two string `"A""B"` are concatenated. This is convention of **language C**.

Answer (score 1):

Try `gcc -E` to display the preprocessed source code. You will have something like this:

```
int main()
{
    const char THREE[6] = "three";
    printf("one" ", two and" "%s.\n", THREE );
    return 0;
}
```

Then, follow the correct answer from @shafik-yaghmour

Comment: Your answer should have been posted as a comment on @Shafik's answer. All you've provided is "gcc -E" commentary, which doesn't answer the question posted.