# Confused about C string constants

Tags: c, string

When I came across this [C language implementation of Porters Stemming algorithm](http://tartarus.org/martin/PorterStemmer/c.txt) I found a C-ism I was confused about.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void test( char *s )
{
    int len = s[0];

    printf("len= %i\n", len );

    printf("s[len] = %c\n", s[len] );
}

int main()
{
    test("\07" "abcdefg");

    return 0;
}
```

and output:

```
len = 7
s[len] = g
```

However, when I input

```
test("\08" "abcdefgh");
```

or any string constant that is longer than 7 with the corresponding length in the first pair of parenthesis ( i.e. `test("\09" "abcdefghi");` the output is

```
len = 0
s[len] =
```

But any input like `test("\01" "abcdefgh");` prints out the character in that position ( if we call the first character position 1 and not 0 for the moment )

It appears if `test( char *s )` reads the number in the first pair of parenthesis ( how it does this I am not sure since I thought s[0] would be able to only read a single char, i.e. the '\' ) and prints the last character at that index + 1 of the string constant in the second pair of parenthesis.

My question is this: It seems as if we are passing two string constants into `test( char *s )`. What exactly is happening here, meaning, how does the compiler seem to "split" up the string over two pairs of parenthesis? Another question one might have is, is a string of the form `"blah" "abcdefg"` one consecutive block of memory? It may be the case that I have overlooked something elementary, but even so I would like to know what I overlooked. I know this is a basic concept but I could not find a clear example or situation on the web that explains this and in all honesty I don't follow the output. Any helpful comments are welcomed.

Comment: [Adjacent string literals are concatenated by the preprocessor](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20548262/1708801)

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: Yeah, I think that's intentional. Looks as though the code is trying to emulate Pascal strings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are at least three things going on here:

- Literal strings juxtaposed against one another are concatenated by the compiler. `"a" "b"` is exactly the same as `"ab"`.
- The backslash is an escape character, which means it is not copied literally into the resulting string. The notation `\01` means "the character with ASCII value 1".
- The notation `\0...` means an *octal* character constant. Octal numbers are base 8, made up from digits that range from 0 through 7 inclusive. 8 is not a valid octal constant, so `"\08"` does not follow `"\07"`.

Comment: Note that notation for octals is not necessarily `\0...` - for example, `\33` is a perfectly valid octal character constant. `\08` is interpreted as `\0` followed by `8`.

Comment: Yeah, length-prefixed strings in C are pretty unusual and you won't find much support for them anywhere.

Comment: The **reason** the length byte and "actual string" are separated may warrant some extra explanation.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is not in the length of the string, but in the `\o` syntax for specifying non-printable values in string literals. `\o`, `\oo`, and `\ooo` denote *octal* constants, i.e. a single character whose value is written in base 8. Since `08` in `\08` doesn't represent a valid base 8 number, it is interpreted as `\0` followed by the ASCII character `8`.

To fix the problem, represent 8 as `\10` or `\010`:

```
test("\007" "abcdefg");
test("\010" "abcdefgh");
```

...or switch to hexadecimal, where the `\x` prefix makes the base more explicit to the casual reader:

```
test("\x07" "abcdefg");
test("\x08" "abcdefgh");
test("\x09" "abcdefghi");
test("\x0a" "abcdefghij");
...
```

Answer (score 1):

`\number` in a character or string literal is means the character whose code is the value `number`. `number` is interpreted in octal, so the first non-octal digit terminates the number. So `"\07"` is a one-character string containing the character with code `7`, but `\08` is a two-character string containing the character with code `0` followed by the digit `8`.

Additionally, code `0` the null terminator that's used in C to indicate the end of the string. So that second string ends at the beginning, because its first byte is the terminator. This why the length of the string in your second example is `0`.

Answer (score 1):

When two or more string literals are adjacent (separated only by white-space), the compiler will join them into a single string.  Therefore  `"\07" "abcdefg"` is equivalent to `"\07abcdefg".`
"\07" is an octal escape. An octal escape ends after three digits or with first non-octal character. So, when you enter "\08", `8` is a non octal character therefore escape ends and `0` is stored at `s[0]`.
Now, `len` is `0` and printing `s[len]` will try to print the character at `s[0]` which has a non printable ASCII code (Only character above ASCII value above `32` are printable).