# C literals concatenation

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

C allows us to concatenate literal list via MACRO.

```
#define H "HELLO"
#define W "WORLD"
#define HW H " " W
```

It would result out in expansion of `HELLO WORLD`.

Same can be achieved via initialiser list.

```
char A[] = "Hello" " " "World";
```

It would also result out in expansion of `HELLO WORLD`.

Same applies to `printf("%s\n", "HELLO" " " "WOLRD");`.

even here, It would result out in expansion to `HELLO WORLD`.

In all the above cases, we can see, string literals are concatenated :)

```
char B[] = "HELLO";
char C[] = " ";
char D[] = "WORLD";
char E[] = B C D;
```

but same doesn't reflects with variables.
why is it so?

Comment: Because variables are not the same as literals?

Comment: There isn't an answer other than "you cannot concatenate variables that are arrays using the notation shown".  It isn't the design of C.  If you've not already encountered them, look up `strcpy()` and `strcat()` and relatives from `<string.h>`; that's how you deal with variables.

Comment: Adjacent string literal [concatenation is done during translation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20548262/1708801)

Comment: Yes, thats true that variables and literals are not same. But how does it stores the literals and variable in memory should be rather more important. and I guess, that should be the reason for behaviour.. but not sure :(

Comment: Your question is more or less on a par with "why do some countries drive on the {right,left}?"  There isn't a particularly good reason; it is a largely arbitrary choice.  The way C was designed simply doesn't support concatenating variables in the way you seek.  It could probably have been designed to do so, but the language wouldn't be C any more.

Comment: @NitinTripathi, in days of yore, when I was first learning C, it was the reverse I found surprising: that adjacent string literals were concatenated at all. I did not then and do not now find anything surprising in the fact that the values of variables cannot be concatenated in the same way.  The thing to remember is that the concatenation of literals is a *compile-time* behavior, whereas concatenating the values of variables can happen only at run time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but same doesn't reflects with variables. why is it so?

Several reasons:

1. String concatenation is done by the preprocessor *before* the source text is parsed (this is possible because string literals have the `"` delimiter, making them easy to recognize at this level);
2. There is a well-defined initializer syntax that simply doesn't allow for an initialization like `char E[] = B C D;`;
3. Similarly, the *expressions* `B`, `C`, and `D` are converted to pointer expressions and not treated as arrays of `char`;

Additionally, not all arrays of `char` are guaranteed to store *strings*.  And you'd have to set aside storage for the concatenated strings.

> What does the standard say about it?

C programs are translated in 8 distinct stages (see section 5.1.1.2 of the [C 2011 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) for details).

Stages 1 through 6 describe the actions of the preprocessor; physical source file characters are mapped onto the *source character set*, trigraphs are converted to single-character equivalents, physical lines with trailing `\` characters are spliced into single logical source lines, comments are replaced with a single whitespace character, macros are expanded, preprocessing directives are executed, and, as the last step of the preprocessor, string literals are concatenated.

Stage 7 is where the massaged source text is actually *parsed* by the compiler.

Stage 8 is basically the linker step.

**TL/DR**

String literals are special, and are treated specially by the preprocessor.

Answer (score 1):

Neither macros nor initializer lists are responsible for what you're observing.

When C finds two **literals** adjacent to each other in the source code it concatenates them. So `"hello" "world"` is the same as typing `"helloworld"`.

Comment: To add to your answer: This concatenation occurs before C has the notion of variables and types, thus variables cannot influence this process.